# Azure AD B2C WebApp calling WebApi -> Signature validation failed

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to access my WebApi from my WebApp using token authentication. I am successfully logged in into my WebApp. I then ask for a new Token:

```
var signedInUserID = _idenetityParser.Parse().Id.ToString();

var userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, _httpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();

var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
     _azureOptions.ClientId,
     _azureOptions.Authority,
     "http://localhost/",
      new ClientCredential(_azureOptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);


var result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new string[] { "https://tests.onmicrosoft.com/company/rw" }, cca.Users.FirstOrDefault(), _azureOptions.Authority, false);

return result.AccessToken;
```

This works fine and I get a new AccessToken with the scope requested.

Then I call the WebApi using a HttpClient, setting the Authorization Header to Bearer and pass in the token. After that I get the following error:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException:
>   IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided
>   to validate the signature.

I use the following setup on the WebApi:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Authority = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/", Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Tenant"], Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Policy"]),
    Audience = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
        OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated
    }
});
```

I checked the Authority on both the WebApp and the WebApi they are the same. I am running on local dev machine using https.

Not sure what to do next to find the issue. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: have you reviewed [this sample prj - active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi)?

Comment: specifically: TaskWebApp\App_Start\Startup.cs

Comment: Yes I have. But this not a .net core application. But I was able to get my app authenticated with adding RequireHttpsMetadata = false. I will update my original question asap.

Comment: You should avoid setting RequireHttpsMetadata to false as you'd be forgoing the benefits of Https, a big security no-no. If that fixed it, then there's something in your machine's cert chain that's preventing it from accepting the SSL cert from https://login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work in the end without turning https off? I can't seem to get it to work even doing that.

Comment: To be honest, no not yet...still in developing mode at the moment. Sorry I can't be more of help here. Would be happy if you would post back if you get it to work.